# How do I mock js-cookie and jwt-decode to update its value based on the test

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to test a function that calls js-cookie to retrieve info from the Cookies and then try to decode it if that value exists. I want to update the value of the cookie based on the test but this approach I have to update js-cookie's value at the top.

```
import { isLoggedInVar } from 'cache';

jest.mock('js-cookie', () => {
  return {
    get: jest.fn(() => {
      return 'token';
    }),
  };
});

jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => () => ({ exp: 10 }));

describe('isLoggedIn', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    isLoggedInVar();
  });

  it('should return false', () => {
    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toEqual(false); // this always returns true as "token" is set for ALL the tests
  });


  it('should return true', () => {
    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

For all the tests, I get 'token' but I want to change token as empty in individual tests

Comment: Move the jest.fn() *outside* the jest.mock call so you can do e.g. `getCookie.mockReturnValue('othertoken')`? The easiest thing is to let Jest auto mock the module, don't pass the mock implementation, then you can import the mock in the test the same way you do in the code under test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you show an example for it will work? ```const getMock = jest.fn(() => {
  return null;
});

jest.doMock('js-cookie', () => {
  return {
    get: getMock(),
  };
});
jest.doMock('jwt-decode', () => () => ({ exp: 10 }));``` Did you mean like this?

getMock.mockReturnValue('token');
    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toEqual(true);

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [jest.doMock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) is something you might need. This allows you to mock at `test` level but keep in mind, do not `import/require` the testing module before you mock it.

Here is the example based on your code:

```js
describe('isLoggedIn', () => {
  it('should return false', () => {

    jest.doMock('js-cookie', () => {
      return {
        get: jest.fn(() => {
          return null;
        }),
      };
    });    
    jest.doMock('jwt-decode', () => () => ({ exp: 10 }));
    
    // We `require` in sync function we want to test after having mock set
    const { isLoggedInVar } = require('cache');
    
    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toEqual(false); // this always returns true as "token" is set for ALL the tests
  });


  it('should return true', () => {
    jest.doMock('js-cookie', () => {
      return {
        get: jest.fn(() => {
          return 'token';
        }),
      };
    });    
    jest.doMock('jwt-decode', () => () => ({ exp: 10 }));
    
    const { isLoggedInVar } = require('cache');
    
    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

In case you don't want to use `require` keyword, you can follow up the above link to work with esmodule statement `import`.

#### In case of being keen to not use `doMock`:

You can mock the entire module without providing a factory but then we provide in each test like following:

```js
import { isLoggedInVar } from 'cache';
import { get } from 'js-cookie';

jest.mock('js-cookie');

describe('isLoggedIn', () => {  

  it('should return false', () => {
    get.mockReturnValue(null)
    isLoggedInVar();
    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toEqual(false);
  });

  it('should return true', () => {
    get.mockReturnValue('token')
    isLoggedInVar();
    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: This did not work for me, I tried both of these approaches

Comment: Can you share your real implementation or a minimal reproducible repo?